# How to stop XAMPP/MySQL from defaulting to IPv6?

Tags: networking, mysql, xampp, ipv6

I installed XAMPP for Linux on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04. I started all servers and ran `netstat -tupln`.

The `mysql` server is running on IPv6:

```
tcp6    0    0 :::3306    :::*    LISTEN    2818/mysqld
```

I followed the answer here on how to disable IPv6 completely for Ubuntu 14.04. I completed all the steps successfully and  `cat/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`
returns `1`, which should indicate that IPv6 is disabled.

I rebooted my system and started XAMPP again, but it still indicates `tcp6`.

How can I force XAMPP or `mysqld` from using IPv6? Alternatively how can I completely disable IPv6 so that no services can start on it?

Answer (score 2):

Completely disabling IPv6 is getting harder and harder these days. In many operating systems and for many applications it's a crucial component now. if you really want to remove all traces of IPv6 then your only option might be to recompile a lot of software with different options.

I think the best option In most cases is to leave it enabled and configure your firewall to block unwanted traffic. That way the software can continue to use I use IPv6 sockets (which on Linux and other operating systems also can handle incoming IPv4 connections) while your system is protected against unwanted traffic.

Of course what the best alternative is depends on why you want to disable IPv6. The answer above won't help if your goal is to lower memory usage or something like that.